# Ember Nested Model: Find and remove child element from model

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a nested model which is used to construct the tree view.

Here, I have two action handlers which is used to delete the folders based on the passed "id" param.

So when I pass the first level folder "id", I can remove the elements from the model using filterBy().

But when I pass the second/third level folder "id", and use filterBy to filter through the model using "id", it returns an empty value.

Here, how can I can filter through the sub level model using id?

In Template:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     <button {{action deleteFolder_1 '1'}}>Delete Folder_1</button> 
     <br><br>

     <button {{action deleteFolder_11 '11'}}>Delete Folder_11</button>
     <ul>
       {{#each model}}
          {{partial "tree"}}
       {{/each}}
     </ul>
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_tree">
    <li>{{foldername}}</li>
     <ul>
      {{#each children}}
        {{partial "tree"}}
      {{/each}}
     </ul>
 </script>
```

In app.js

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
    return [
    {
    id: '1',
    foldername: 'Folder 1',
    children:[{
      id: '11',
      foldername: 'Sub Folder 11',
      children: [{
          id: '111',
          foldername: 'Sub Folder 111',
          children: []
        }]
     }]
   }, 
  {
   id: '2',
   foldername: 'Folder 2',
   children: []
  },
  {
   id: '3',
   foldername: 'Folder 3',
   children:[]
 }];
 },
 actions: { 

  deleteFolder_1: function (id) {
    var obj = this.controller.content.filterBy('id',id);
    this.controller.content.removeObjects(obj);
  },
  deleteFolder_11: function (id) {
     var obj =      this.controller.content.filterBy('id',id);
     this.controller.content.removeObjects(obj);
      // How can I delete the subfolder here? How can I find the sub id? Is there any way to find id recursively.
   }

 }

 });
```

JSBIN DEMO: [LINK](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zunok/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recursively traverse the tree. Here is a function that will delete the entry based on the id you pass. This function will traverse the whole tree to find a match.

```
deleteFolderById: function (id) {      
  function recursiveFilter(item, index, array) {
    item = Em.Object.create(item);
    if (item.id === id) {
      return null;
    } else {
      item.set('children', item.children.map(recursiveFilter).compact());
      return item;
    }
  }

  var filtered = this.get('controller.content').map(recursiveFilter).compact();      
  this.set('controller.content', filtered);
}
```

[Here is the working demo](http://jsbin.com/vicey/2/edit).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I implemented in my code and it's working fine. I can Add node/Delete node/Rename node using your code. How can I handle node draggable and droppable events and rearrange it in the model?

Comment: You will need to do some research on implementing drag and drop. Im not really used with those api's. The basic idea while rearranging is to use the 'insertAt' and 'removeAt' method for rearranging. I noticed that you are not accepting any answers for any of your question.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I will research on drag and drop. I have accepted my answers too.

Comment: How can I open/close nodes when click on the nodes?

Comment: Im not sure what u mean by open/close. If you mean by showing/hiding subfolder, try this http://jsbin.com/vicey/5/edit